# PlaceholderAdmin throws <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: django, django-cms

I've wrote a plugin for django-cms which has it's own model with one PlaceholderField. When I add a PlaceholderAdmin for model admin I'm getting this on admin site:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Caught TypeError while rendering: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Exception Location: <blablapath>/python2.6/site-packages/cms/forms/widgets.py in render, line 199
```

I've been searching for solution and found only some problems with django-cms example which would not run without uncommenting some path in urls.py so I guess it might be problem with urls, especially that I do some magic in my urls. The question is: what conditions should hold for django-cms url's to be valid? Any ideas? Any solutions? Anybody had this problem before?

Comment: Don't you think it would be useful to show the code of your field?

Comment: That's the problem. There is almost nothing to paste because it's quite simple `content_placeholder = PlaceholderField('simple_content_placeholder')` . It's not my field but django-cms field.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is caused when you are not subclassing the `PlaceholderAdminField` in your admin class.

For example:

```
from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import PlaceholderAdmin
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sidebar = PlaceholderField('sidebar')

class MyAdmin(PlaceholderAdmin):
    """ Put your usual admin stuff here. If you use fieldset,
    include the sidebar as its own tuple """
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('name',),
        }),

        ('Sidebar', {
            'classes': ('plugin-holder', 'plugin-holder-nopage'),
            'fields': ('sidebar',)
        }),
    )
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyAdmin)
```

Comment: This didn't help much but since then i've realized that the problem might be because I use [multilingual-ng](https://github.com/ojii/django-multilingual-ng) with it.

Comment: Ah. I was getting the same error as you, and it was because I wasn't subclassing PlaceholderAdmin in its admin class.

Comment: Thats a lot! This fixed the issue for me! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Well, this appears to be a bug in Django-CMS. I've never used it, but looking at the code, it's clear that the default formfield for `PlaceholderField` creates a lambda which takes a single argument - a queryset, but the render function for that formfield calls the lambda with two arguments - the request, and the queryset.

Probably the best way to fix this is to define your own subclass of `PlaceholderField` which redefines the `formfield` method so it returns a correct lambda:

```
class FixedPlaceholderField(PlaceholderField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return self.formfield_for_admin(None, lambda request, qs: qs, **kwargs)
```

and use this field in your model instead.

If this fixes it, it's probably worth raising a bug in Django-CMS.

Comment: That's what I thought but it didn't help because i got other errors so I think it's somewhere on my side. Still this lambda thing feels strange so anyway I'll probably report this as a bug

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've solved the problem for me. I still don't know what was happening but maybe my answer will help you figure it out ;).
I've used a method:

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
    ...
```

which substituted one text field into TinyMCE editor. When I removed the whole method the problem vanished. If I have time later on maybe I'll try to dig into it a little bit deeper. 
I'm still not convinced that that was the only problem. I have a hunch that it also might be something with data because I've filled placeholder with text plugin from code.

Hope it helps somehow.